# set different wallpaper for each desktop in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

In Ubuntu if you press Ctrl+Alt+Arrow Down, a new desktop would be created.
However, it seems all desktops share the same wallpaper.
Is it possible to set a different wallpaper for each desktop?